# htaccess Redirect subdomain only without a path

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I am redirecting the follow domain examples.

```
example.domain.tld to domain.tld/foo/example-foo.html
```

This works correct, but I need to use another approach when the same subdomain has a path including a specific slug. So I want to prevent with the current redirection I wrote the redirection on this situation

```
example.domain.tld/foo/
```

My current htaccess redirect

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(www|staging)\. [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*)\.(.*)\.de [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^(foo|foo2)[NC] # <== not working
RewriteRule (.*) https://www.%2.de/foo/%1-foo.html [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Not sure to understand what you really want, but I can see following problem. The backreferences `%2` and `%1` are backref to the LAST `RewriteCond` before the `RewriteRule`. So you should at least move up your last `RewriteCond` so that `RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*)\.(.*)\.de [NC]` is the last just before `RewriteRule`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`REQUEST_URI` must start with `/` and you need to keep capturing conditions in the end.

This should work:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(www|staging)\. [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(^|/)(foo|foo2) [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([^.]+)\.([^.]+)\.de [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) https://www.%2.de/foo/%1-foo.html [R=301,L]
```

Comment: I've found the solution. It doesn't need to start with '/' but I made the mistakte using '!^' instead of a single '!'. Thanks for your answer